# Sensitive or not sensitive gate?

Tags: triac, sensitivity

If there is nothing about it in the datasheet, how can I find out if it is a sensitive or not sensitive gate?

Comment: The question is answered with great satisfaction. Otherwise my confusion about sensitive or not sensitive gate when I saw this mentioned often and found no answer to this in datasheet, because I did not know that this referred to the quadrant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply look at the gate trigger current specification in the [datasheet](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/switching_thyristors/littelfuse_thyristor_lxx08xx_qxx08xx_qxx08xhx_datasheet.pdf.pdf):

[image]

A "sensitive gate" triac will have a gate trigger current at 25°C in quadrants excluding IV that around 5mA or 10mA (or less). Trigger current will be much higher when the triac is cold and may be very high or not guaranteed at all in quadrant IV (positive gate, negative MT2 vs. MT1).

It is not necessarily a good thing to have a sensitive gate, as it often goes hand-in-glove with lower tolerance for dv/dt, which can be an issue when switching inductive loads or with mains transients.

Comment: Well ok, so it's depending on the quadrant, that dropped into place :) Thank you :)